# How to change Telerik RadTimeBar label placement?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a Telerik RadTimeBar in my XAML, I could easily customize whatever I wanted except the interval label placement. In the telerik demos intervals are somehow drawn inside the actual time bar, not on top of that. Here's a snapshot demonstrating it. I need to position day intervals the way Weeks are displayed here:

[image]

Whatever I do, I keep getting this rendered on the screen:

[image]

Here's my XAML:

```
<telerik:RadTimeBar Grid.Row="2" x:Name="multiDayTimeBar"
                                PeriodStart="{Binding TimeBarRangeStart}" 
                                PeriodEnd="{Binding TimeBarRangeEnd}"
                                SelectionChanged="multiDayTimeBar_SelectionChanged"                                    
                                SelectionStart="{Binding TimeBarSelectedStart, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                SelectionEnd="{Binding TimeBarSelectedEnd, Mode=TwoWay}"                                                                     
                                ScrollMode="None"                                                                        
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">


                <telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>                        
                    <telerik:DayInterval />
                    <telerik:HourInterval/>                        
                </telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>

                <telerik:RadLinearSparkline Margin="0,3" 
                                            LineStroke="#FF767676"                                                 
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding TimeBarSource}"
                                            XValuePath="Timestamp" 
                                            YValuePath="DemandValue" />

            </telerik:RadTimeBar>
```

Digging through the API documentation didn't help. Telerik's demo codes do not hint something either. If someone had a similar problem, any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the WPF UI demos installed on my computer. After taking a look at the TimeBar example they give this code:

```
<telerik:RadTimeBar Name="timeBar1" Height="150"
                            PeriodStart="{Binding PeriodStart, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            PeriodEnd="{Binding PeriodEnd, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            VisiblePeriodStart="{Binding VisiblePeriodStart, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            VisiblePeriodEnd="{Binding VisiblePeriodEnd, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionStart="{Binding SelectedStartDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionEnd="{Binding SelectedEndDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            MinSelectionRange="{Binding MinSelectionRange, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsSnapToIntervalEnabled="True">
            <telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
                <telerik:QuarterInterval />
                <telerik:MonthInterval />
                <telerik:WeekInterval />
                <telerik:DayInterval />
                <telerik:HourInterval/>
            </telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
            <telerik:RadLinearSparkline LineStroke="#FF767676" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerInfos}" XValuePath="Date" YValuePath="UniqueVisitors" />
        </telerik:RadTimeBar>
```

Which they say produces this time bar:

[image]

Not sure if this will help you or not, but the only thing that I could see that was different is that they set the `IsSnapToIntervalEnabled="True"` the `VisiblePeriodStart` and the `VisiblePeriodEnd`. Think these might need to be set?

Comment: I also have the codes and I noticed the differences that you described. Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Just following up to see if that was what your problem was? Just curious. I use telerik tools quite a bit and would like to know if this fixed your issue.